# fb:visible-to-connection not working?

Tags: php, fbml

Hi i have created new iFrame APP.

this is code part:

```
<fb:visible-to-connection>Welcome, fans!<fb:else>Become fan</fb:else></fb:visible-to-connection>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help me out??

I also tried doing this with newest Facebook PHP SDK. Unfortunately i can check it first i user accepted the APP, which is not the point in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seamless way to check if user likes page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page)

Comment: fb:visible-to-connection was for fbml pages and is not supported by iframe pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am almost sure that is not working anymore.

To detect a like or non-liker you can use the signed request to get that data. 
It gets passed to a tab when it is loaded.

```
<?php
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
?>
```

Then in the body of your HTML:

```
<?php
    if ($data["page"]["liked"]!=1) {
        echo('<div id="NON_LIKER_CONTENT"> <img src="nonliker.jpg" width="520"/></div>');
    }  else {
        echo('<div id="LIKER_CONTENT"> <img src="liker.jpg" width="520"/></div>');
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: unfortunately signed_request isn't loaded in my tab...

signed_request for Canvas is active under settings tab...

any other idea ?